# HTTP Status 500: When using form:input tag in jsp

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp

When I use `<form:input path="name" />` inside my jsp page it show HTTP Status 500 Error.

The issue that I'm facing is because of this tag `<form:input path="name">` But If I remove this tag and use normal input tag it's working fine for me.

Any Help will be Appreciated.

I Also Include `Taglib for form`

`<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>`

My Jsp file is[image]

Code Inside My controller is
[image]

and The Error it's displaying to me is
[image]

Comment: Is there a cause in the end of that Stacktrace (another Exception)?

Comment: @hinneLinks Yes, it's `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ModelAndView like below and create a bean  with setters and getters of property "name".

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView insert() {

      return new ModelAndView("script", "command" , new MyBean());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView attackHandler(@ModelAttribute("myBean")MyBean mybean) {

       System.out.println(mybean.getName());

      return new ModelAndView("script", "command" , mybean);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please provide the Bean(`with setter and getter`) for you input value and Include your bean in servlet method `insert and attackHandller` .

like

```
public ModelAndView attackHandller(@ModelAttribute("beanData")  @Validated BeanData beanData, BindingResult bindingResult,Model model){}
```